# Java array what should i do in order to read from the array and display

Tags: java, arrays

what should i do in order to read from the array and display it.
i try using these but there is an error for the input.next();

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringeEX
{
  static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\r\n");


  public static void main(String[] args)
  {     
    String ColourOne[] ={"Black","Brown","Red","Orange","Yellow","Green","Blue","Violet","Grey","White"};

    System.out.println("==========================================================");
    System.out.println("Black  = 0," + "\t" + "Brown = 1," + "\t" + "Red   = 2,"+ "\t" +"Orange = 3");
    System.out.println("Yellow = 4," + "\t" + "Green = 5," + "\t" + "Blue  = 6," + "\t" +"Violet = 7");
    System.out.println("*** NOTE: ***"+"\t"+"Grey  = 8,"+ "\t"+"white = 9");
    System.out.println("==========================================================");
    System.out.print("Please enter the number for the colour :");
    ColourOne = input.next();
 for(int i = 0; i < ColourOne.length; i++) 
     System.out.println(ColourOne[i]); 

  }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html

Comment: Seriously, dude? Read a book on java before posting.

Comment: You might want to look at loops: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop

Comment: ColourOne = input.next();
for(int i = 0; i < ColourOne.length; i++)
System.out.println(ColourOne[i]); i try using these but there is an error for the input.next();

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to String[]

 at StringeEX.main(StringeEX.java:18)

Comment: you are trying to assign a `String` to a String Array. use a seperate variable to store value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to store the scanner input into the array. you should specify a separate variable. Arrays are zero-indexed, so when getting a value from array use `ArrayName[someNumber]` where someNumber refers to the element in the array. the first element starts at 0.

```
int i = input.nextInt();
System.out.println(ColourOne[i]);
```